# Reusing UITableViewCells with a UISearchDisplayController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I came up with an issue that I managed to fix, but the thing is that I don't understand how it was fixed, lol. Can anyone help educate me?

I am making a simple table view app with an array of arrays with strings split into sections using `UILocalizedIndexedCollation`. I also have a `UISearchBar` setup in the header of the tableview that the user can use to find a particular string.

It got a little weird when I setup the `UISearchDisplayController` methods and added a bunch of if statements to pull the search results into the table view.

Here is my `cellForRow:atIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Simple Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    // Get a cell from the table view.
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        // Grab a cell for the search results
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    } else {
        // Grab a cell for the main table view
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    // Setup and return the cell.
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = self.sectionsArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

This works just fine, but when I change the section where I grab a cell from the `self.tableView` to:

```
  // Get a cell from the table view.
  cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I get the following error when I run the simulator:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for rect at invalid index path ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 2})'**

It isn't a huge deal if I don't understand why this happens, but it would be nice to know!

Thanks for reading through this :)